# CSS Navbar Code Diagnostic

Tags: html, css

I customized my navbar to fit the appropriate style. I have searched for many other recourses to help me out on this one but my skills are not there yet. The first question i would like to know in my css, what centered my navbar? What make the buttons in my navbar specifically assign to where they are on the page? My other question is when you hover over the buttons on the edge what piece of code tells the navbar to have the rounded edge?

JSFddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r3cj2zkL/

Code:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto; }
nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0; }
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden; }
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%; }
nav ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 0;
   display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  
    #fff 0%, #fff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%,#fff), 
    color-stop(100%,#fff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  
    #fff 0%,#fff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  
    #fff 0%,#fff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  
    #fff 0%,#fff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
    startColorstr='#fff', 
    endColorstr='#fff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:focus,
nav ul li a:visited,
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none; }
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active {
      background: #D3D3D3; /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  
        #D3D3D3 0%, #D3D3D3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        color-stop(0%,#D3D3D3), 
        color-stop(100%,#D3D3D3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
       background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  
        #D3D3D3 0%,#D3D3D3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
       background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  
         #D3D3D3 0%,#D3D3D3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  
    #D3D3D3 0%,#D3D3D3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
    startColorstr='#000', 
    endColorstr='#000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  }
nav ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; }
nav ul li:last-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px; }
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: why do you have pure white gradients? And the unused classes? Your code is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What centered my navbar?

The whole page is centered because of the `max-width: 960px` and `margin: auto` on the `body` tag. The navbar takes up the entire width of the 960px page because of the width set on the `li`s.

> What make the buttons in my navbar specifically assign to where they are on the page?

Each `li` has `left: float`, this makes them "line up" next to each other horizontally (starting on the left) as long as there is enough space. Since there are 5, and they are set to `width: 20%`, they all end up beside each other. Floats take a bit of time to understand, you can read more [here on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

> What piece of code tells the navbar to have the rounded edge?

The very last part of the CSS: `border-top-left-radius: 8px;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

**1 - what centered my navbar? What make the buttons in my navbar specifically assign to where they are on the page?**

Your nav is not actually centered. It is expanded on full width. The body is with `margin: auto;`. And the `<li>` items inside it contain anchor tags `<a>`. Those tags are centering the text with `text-align: center;`

```
nav ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    /*...*/
```

See the hierarchy? `a` inside `li` inside `ul` inside `nav`.

**2 - what piece of code tells the navbar to have the rounded edge?**

The one with the pseudo selectors `:first-child` and `:last-child`:

```
nav ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
nav ul li:last-child a {
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```